# How to install gcj?

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, gcc

[image]

It seems I need to install gcc but:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`sudo apt-get install  libgcj6-dev` (you can try this from synaptic as well)

```
sudo apt-get install gcj-jdk
```

Answer (score 2):

To install `gcj` you need to type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gcj
```

Your screenshots may be related to something else that could have failed to install correctly.  Suggestion to resolve this before running the above command would be:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```